# Compare two Selects or tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, compare

I have two tables **Temporal_Group** and **Product_Group**

If I perform the following query to the group table:

```
SELECT group.id_product FROM group
WHERE id_group=2
```

I returned:

```
id_product
----------------
5
```

Now, if I do query the temporal table

```
SELECT temporal.id_product FROM temporal
```

return

```
id_product
----------------
5
14
```

I want is to compare these 2 results in a query and return the difference to me ... The result should be out **14** ... I tried with this:

```
SELECT group.id_product FROM group
WHERE group.id_product
NOT IN (
SELECT temporal.id_product
FROM temporal
WHERE group.id_product=temporal.id_product
)
AND group.id_group=2
```

But I do not return anything, there is another way to compare those results?
I hope for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt returns the difference `A-B`. I guess you want the symmetric difference `(A-B) UNION (B-A)`:

```
    SELECT id_product
         , 'group' AS only_in_table 
    FROM `group`
    WHERE id_group = 2
      AND id_product NOT IN 
          ( SELECT id_product
            FROM temporal
          )
UNION ALL
    SELECT id_product
         , 'temporal' AS only_in_table 
    FROM temporal
    WHERE id_product NOT IN 
          ( SELECT id_product
            FROM `group`
            WHERE id_group = 2
          )
```

---

It's not good to use reserved words like `group` to name tables or columns, because you have to somehow tell the SQL engine that it's not the "group" in the reserved `GROUP BY` In MySQL this can be done by enclosing them in backticks: `` `group` ``.

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed .... comparison in both cases, thank you very much. excuse me... how to apply a COUNT () to all query?

P. S. Do not worry, I wrote "group" for example ... the names of my fields are long XD

Answer (score 2):

For finding all items that exist in either table and not the other;

```
select id_product from 
     (select distinct id_product from `group` where id_group = 2 union all 
      select distinct id_product from temporal) a 
group by id_product having count(id_product)<2;
```

(find all distinct id_product in both tables, union together and display all that only show up once)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group.id_product FROM group
WHERE id_group=2


EXCEPT


SELECT temporal.id_product FROM temporal
```

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL has not the `EXCEPT` operator.

Comment: MariaDB >= 10.3.0 has
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/except/

Answer (score 0):

You could try `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    g.id_product 
FROM 
    group g
FULL OUTER JOIN 
   temporal t 
ON 
   g.id_product = t.id_product 
WHERE
   g.id_group = 2 AND (g.id_product IS NULL OR t.id_product IS NULL)
```

As @Bill metioned, Mysql does not support full outer join, so you could use `union` instead.

```
(SELECT
    g.id_product
FROM
    group g
LEFT JOIN
    temporal t
ON
    g.id_product = t.id_product
WHERE
    g.id_group = 2 AND t.id_product IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT
    g.id_product
FROM
    group g
RIGHT JOIN
    temporal t
ON
    g.id_product = t.id_product
WHERE
    g.id_group = 2 AND g.id_product IS NULL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not support full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

How about a very simple LEFT JOIN / IS NULL.   By doing the LEFT join, it will find those products in the 'group' table where the group ID = 2.  If it finds one, the g.id_product will have a value... if NOT, it will be NULL... the set you WANT to get.

```
select t.id_product
   from
      temporal t
         left join `group` g
            on t.id_product = g.id_product
           AND g.id_group = 2
   where
      g.id_product IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it only works side-temporal group ... if the table "t" has more records than the table "g" does not return anything.